# Azue Function V2 - Event hub trigger not respecting host configuration maxBatchSize

Tags: azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I have a function with a event hub trigger. 
That function is v2.
That functions has event hub trigger.
Host.json is the following

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "eventHub": {
      "maxBatchSize": 1024,
      "prefetchCount": 1024,
      "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1
    }
  }
}
```

When checking the number of messages per batch, the maximum I can see is 10.
I created a similar function v1 and I get batches with bigger numbers.

The event hub in question has 32 partitions and is receiving around 700 messages per minute (+- 22 per partition per minute) and outputting around 100 messages. The function does take quite some time to execute, but that is no excuse for such low amount of messages per batch, if anything, it should increase the amount of messages per batch.

Anyone knows what am I missing? is this a v2 bug?

Note: using lib Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHub (3.0.0-beta8) as indicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the documentation available [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json-(v2)), you have a typo:

```
"eventHubs": {
    "maxBatchSize": 256,
    "prefetchCount": 512
}
```

It is eventHub**s**. In V1 it was singular, now it is plural.

Comment: Dumb thing on my part. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a note for anyone coming along later, that documentation now shows that the `maxBatchSize` and `prefetchCount` are contained in an `eventProcessorOptions` object like so: `"eventHubs": {            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 5, "eventProcessorOptions": {                "maxBatchSize": 256, "prefetchCount": 512 } }`